# ProgrammingError at / relation "xxx" does not exist / Error during template rendering

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm building something with django on heroku and I'm getting "Error during template rendering" error but ONLY on heroku. when running locally everything works fine. in addition, I'm printing the field I'm trying to render before rendering the page and I see it exists and valid. the template is very simple:

this is the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from perfil import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',


    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.lista_dato),
)
```

this is the models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Dato(models.Model):
    #author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nacimiento = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    cedula = models.IntegerField(max_length=50)
    tarjeta_profesional = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    celular = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    estudio = models.TextField()
    experiencia_laboral = models.TextField()
    fecha_publicar = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publicar(self):
        self.fecha_publicar = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def _str_(self):
        return self.nombre
```

this is lista_dato.html

```
{% extends 'perfil/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

{% for dato in datos %}
<div class="page-header">
<h1><center><a href="https://www.facebook.com/john.e.barbosa">{{ dato.nombre }}</a></center></h1>
</div> 
<div>
<p><h2>Cedula de Ciudadania:</h2> {{ dato.cedula }}</p>
<p><h2>Tarjeta Profesional:</h2> {{ dato.tarjeta_profesional }}</p>
<p><h2>Celular:</h2> {{ dato.celular }}</p>
<p><h2>Email:</h2> {{ dato.email }}</p>
</div>

<div class="post">
<div class="date">Ultima Actualizacion
{{ dato.fecha_publicar }}
</div>
<h1>DESCRIPCIÓN</h1>
<p>{{ dato.descripcion }}</p>
<h1>FORMACIÓN</h1>
<p>{{ dato.estudio}}</p>
<h1>EXPERIENCIA LABORAL</h1>
<p>{{ dato.experiencia_laboral}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

this is the base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
        <head>
            <title>PERFIL</title>
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/miperfil.css' %}">
        </head>
        <body>

           <div class="content container">


               {% block content %}
               {% endblock %}
            </div>



        </body>
    </html>
```

And Finally this is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Dato
# Create your views here.

def lista_dato(request):
    datos = Dato.objects.filter(fecha_publicar__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('fecha_publicar')
    return render(request, 'perfil/lista_dato.html', {'datos': datos})
```

[Error in Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsGuH.png)
[Error in heroku 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1XZZ.png)

This single mistake appears in heroku In the local environment not.

Comment: Do you have admin panel then check the field is there  or not..

Comment: In views print datos, if its null then add if condition in template before for loop.

Comment: where is your perfil_dato defined? Did you run your migrations on the server?

Comment: The administration panel works well locally, in heroku only allows calve and enter the user and then displayed the same error. perfil_Dato never define it , is not a variable created by me, I think it is an internal realción generated with the database . Usman 'm new to Python , Django and Heroku , you explain me how to do the conditional if. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

you might have missed to run migrations (which locally you did). try to run them via

```
heroku run "python manage.py migrate"
```

and retry